# Failable Initializer 'init(fileURL:) cannot override a non-failable initializer

Tags: xcode, swift

I am not sure how to fix this error in Xcode 6.4

```
override init?(fileURL url: NSURL) {
    super.init(fileURL: url)

    let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center.addObserver(self, selector: "thingsDidChange:", name: WhatsitDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

deinit {
    let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Update your Xcode first

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your `init?(_:)` function that can fail and force you to return `nil`. Simply remove the trailing question mark of the init signature.

```
override init(fileURL url: NSURL) {
    super.init(fileURL: url)
    let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    center.addObserver(self, selector: "thingsDidChange:", name: WhatsitDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}
```